# Autowire a component which name ends with an specific suffix

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

Is there a way to Autowire a component which has a name with a specific suffix?

Let's say I have this `interface`

```
public interface Foo {
    void bar();
}
```

and I have some concrete classes that implement that interface

```
@Component
public class AFooImpl1 implements Foo { ... }

@Component
public class SomeFooImpl1 implements Foo { ... }

@Component
public class OtherFooImpl2 implements Foo { ... }
```

Now I want a `class` that only autowire those concrete classes which names end with "Impl1" inside a `List` or `Set` like so:

```
public class Client {
    @Autowired
    private List<Foo> foos;
    ...
}
```

How can I do that?

Is there something like this?

```
public class Client {
    @Autowired
    @Suffix("Impl1")
    private List<Foo> foos;
    ...
}
```

or this?

```
public class Client {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(suffix("Impl1"))
    private List<Foo> foos;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware to be possible what you've suggested. What I would do in your situation:

```
public class Client {
    private List<Foo> foos;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    public Client(List<Foo> myFoos) {
        this.foos = myFoos.stream()
                .filter(foo -> foo.getClass().getName().endsWith("Impl1"))
                .collect(toList());
    }

    @Autowired(required = false)
    public Client() {
        this.foos = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

You autowire all Foo instances and filter them. In this way, the client will have only the foos it needs.

Comment: Thanks I like that, I'll try it